# Why does "nautilus"(Gnome FIles) gives me so smaller size of directory, compared with "du"?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, filesystem, disk-usage, filemanager

I have uncompressed a folder and if I right click in the folder and click properties, I get from nautilus (Gnome Files)

Gnome Files output:

[image: Gnome Files output]

but instead if I do:

```
$ du -sh *
292M    branches
236M    branches.zip
```

so why the folder has SO DIFFERENT size output between the two programs?

Comment: What type of files inside `branches/`  ... What is the file system (NTFS, EXT4 etc.)? ... What is the filesystem's block size?

Comment: Where do you run this `du` command from? What directory? Is it the parent directory of your `branches/` directory? What are the contents of `branches/`? Could you have sparse files, for example?

Comment: @Raffa 1)there are other folders 2)it's BTRFS 3)4096

Comment: @terdon I run du from the parent directory of `branches`.

Comment: I can confirm that Files behaves like this. I tried on one of my own github dirs, and the numbers in Files are just completely wrong. I have no idea why or what it counts, but in any case, always trust command line over GUI tools. The right value is what you get from `du`, not Files. One thing to try: does it report the right size if you enable hidden files? (not the case for me, I had very few hidden files and the discrepancy was in the thousands, but I found https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/805).

Comment: @terdon so it's a bug? the weird thing is that has been closed lol

Comment: @allexj the linked bug report is about hidden files, if you don't enable them it reports the size without the hidden files. Try enabling seeing hidden files in Gnome Files and see if the numbers add up

Comment: @Esther I can confirm (but on a non-Ubuntu system) that they don't add up. Neither the size, nor the number. I counted all files with `find` and compared the result. And the hidden files I had didn't explain the difference (I only had about a dozen hidden files but the difference was in the thousands).

Comment: @terdon not sure about the "count" but I can confirm that the size reported by Files for directories with hundreds of subdirectories in them is always less than actual used disk space but, the difference is not as much as in the question (it becomes more obvious the more the directory contents are) … However, hidden files and directories aren’t calculated in the total size unless the option to show hidden files is set "Ctrl+h" and this can result in a huge difference like in the question … I’ve seen that on Ubuntu up to the latest 23.10

Comment: Yes, @Raffa, but in my case, Files reports "3,714 items, 42.7MB" but `find . -type f -printf '.\n' | wc -l` gives me 6128 results, and `find . -type f  -name '.*' -printf '.\n' | wc -l` shows I only have 14 hidden files, so the numbers aren't even remotely close. Oh, and `du -sch` tells me it's 498M, compared to the 42.7M given by Files.

Comment: @terdon That seems more what  the question shows … What filesystem are you using? I’ve seen some discrepancy on different filesystems … Can you rule out the filesystem part? … BTRFS for example seems to have larger metadata information size that occupy disk but might not be counted in Files for example

Comment: This is on ext4, @Raffa. Pretty standard. I don't really use file managers though, I only opened one now to check this question. So I don't have experience with how common this is, I only ever use the shell for this kind of thing anyway.

Comment: @terdon Files (and other GUI file mangers in a DE) might have some kind of caching/database of its own regarding sizes counts thumbnails etc. … So, that size/count shown  might be pulled from somewhere internal to Files and not real-time per-se from the filesystem … I have not looked into that but, think it’s possible given how it works and IIRC that reported size changes/updates the more Files accesses that directory's contrnts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151586/discussion-between-terdon-and-raffa).

Comment: If `du -sh --apparent-size branches/` reports the same size as in Files, then it's most likely the differences between that and `du -sh branches/` is due to your files (as usual) don't have contents exactly equal to a block size increments plus the meta data of directories might also not be counted in full blocks increments in Files but will be counted with `du -sh` in the same way as well.

Comment: shouldn't we submit a bug report?